# Mapping nested collections of entities - Mapstruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

In my DB schema I have a `Post` entity which can have a list of `PostComment` entities and every `PostComment` entity can have a list of `PostCommentUpvote` entities and a list of `PostCommentDownvote` entities (all self-explanatory I suppose).

`Post`:

```
public class Post {
    ...
    private List<PostComment> postComments;
    ...
}
```

`PostComment`:

```
public class PostComment {
    ...
    private List<PostCommentUpvote> postCommentUpvotes;

    private List<PostCommentDownvote> postCommentDownvotes;
    ...
}
```

`PostCommentUpvote` and `PostCommentDownvote` have the same fields (but semantically are different):

```
public class PostCommentUpvote {
    private Long id;
    ...
}
```

**The end goal** is to get all `Post` comments (`List<PostComment>`)

**Target response DTO**:

```
public class PostCommentsResponseDto {
    
    private List<PostCommentResponseDto> comments;

    private Integer count; // count is the size of the list of PostComments or PostCommentsResponseDto - they are semantically the same, PostCommentsResponseDto just has less fields

}
```

`PostCommentResponseDto`:

```
public class PostCommentResponseDto {

    private Long id;

    private String comment;

    private String username;

    private List<PostCommentUpvoteResponseDto> postCommentUpvotes;

    private List<PostCommentDownvoteResponseDto> postCommentDownvotes;

    private Timestamp createdAt;

    private Timestamp updatedAt;
    
}
```

`PostCommentUpvoteResponseDto` and `PostCommentDownvoteResponseDto` are the same:

```
public class PostCommentUpvoteResponseDto {
    
    private Long id;

}
```

So I'm basically doing mapping from `Post` to `PostCommentsResponseDto`.

`PostMapper`:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { PostCommentMapper.class })
public interface PostMapper {

    @Named("postCommentsMapper")
    default List<PostCommentResponseDto> postCommentsMapper(List<PostComment> postComments) {
       // how to map List<PostComment> to List<PostCommentResponseDto> ?
    }

    @Named("postCommentsQuantityMapper")
    default Integer postCommentsQuantityMapper(List<PostComment> postComments) {
        return postComments.size();
    }

    @Mapping(source = "postComments", target = "comments", qualifiedByName = "postCommentsMapper")
    @Mapping(source = "postComments", target = "count", qualifiedByName = "postCommentsQuantityMapper")
    PostCommentsResponseDto postPostCommentsResponseDtoMapper(Post post);
    
}
```

`PostCommentMapper`:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { PostCommentUpvoteMapper.class, PostCommentDownvoteMapper.class })
public interface PostCommentMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "user.username", target = "username")
    public PostCommentResponseDto postCommentPostCommentResponseDtoMapper(PostComment postComment);

}
```

`PostCommentUpvoteMapper` and `PostCommentDownvoteMapper` are the same:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface PostCommentUpvoteMapper {

    PostCommentUpvoteResponseDto postcommentUpvotePostCommentUpvoteResponseDto(PostCommentUpvote postCommentUpvote);

}
```

**The problem**: How to map `List<PostComment>` to `List<PostCommentResponseDto>` which requires mapping `User` entity to just `String username` and more importantly mapping nested collections `PostCommentUpvoteResponseDto` and `PostCommentDownvoteResponseDto`? With the presented setup the final result is `comments` are null (which is bad because it should be empty array/list) and `counter` is 0 (which is okay because selected post doesn't have any comments)

Please ask if more clarification are needed.

Comment: hey were you able to solve this, I m also stuck on a similar situation :(

Answer (score 1):

hope you found solution, but if you are still need help, this is how I would handle it.

Basically, you should provide a mapper method for mapping an object and also method for mapping list of the same objects and MapStruct will do the rest.

```
@Mapping(source = "user.username", target = "username")
PostCommentResponseDto postCommentToPostCommentResponseDto(PostComment postComment);

List<PostCommentResponseDto> postCommentToPostCommentResponseDto(List<PostComment> postComment);

PostCommentUpvoteResponseDto postCommentUpvoteToPostCommentUpvoteResponseDto(PostCommentUpvote postCommentUpvote);

List<PostCommentUpvoteResponseDto> postCommentUpvoteToPostCommentUpvoteResponseDto(List<PostCommentUpvote> postCommentUpvote);
```

In example above MapStruct will automatically call method `postCommentUpvoteToPostCommentUpvoteResponseDto` inside the `postCommentToPostCommentResponseDto` method.

I have created small working example on GitHub so you can check it.
https://github.com/fpecek/MapstructDemo